# Importing haskell library on Mac OSX gives error

Tags: haskell, compiler-errors

I've just installed GHC 6.6 on OSX 10.6 and importing fails, for example

```
module Main
  where

import IO
```

gives the error:

```
<interactive>:1:84:
   Bad interface file: IO.hi
       IO.hi: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
ghc-6.6: panic! (the 'impossible' happened)
 (GHC version 6.6 for i386-apple-darwin):
       interactiveUI:flush
```

What can I do to resolve this? I'm wondering also if there are any haskell mailing list to potentially subscribe to with errors like these.. my google-fu isn't very great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason you're using ghc-6.6?  It's very old, and mac packaging probably leaves something to be desired.  In particular I would expect that you'll get problems from native 64-bit compiling on Snow Leopard, but probably other issues too.  I would strongly recommend ghc-6.12.x via the [Haskell Platform](http://hackage.haskell.org/platform/mac.html).

The best mailing list for installation problems is probably [haskell-beginners](http://www.haskell.org/mailman/listinfo/beginners).  You could also try [glasgow-haskell-users](http://www.haskell.org/mailman/listinfo/glasgow-haskell-users), but I expect they'd also just tell you to use the Haskell Platform.